# "Undefined variable" when used after assignment in an if-clause

Tags: php, variables, expression, conditional-statements

`if (true && 1 == $x = 1 && $x) {
    echo "Hello world!";
}`

I get an Undefined Variable Notice for $x. Shouldn't the parser know $x at this point, because it solves the If-Clause from left to right?

Comment: Yes, i can accept that. But i would really like to know the answer

Comment: Why the downvote? Because you're asking us "shouldn't this variable already exist at this point" whilst giving us _zero_ way to know one way or the other, and posting a question with which that fundamental flaw is clear, plain and apparent. || Why did _I_ **not** downvote? Because what I wrote, despite being what someone has assumed, is _not true_: your code is very difficult to read and to understand, and almost everyone who comes across it will assume what I started this comment with. Rewrite it.

Comment: I'm sorry. I thought it was readable. I will edit it with the example written by user2864740

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The observed behavior is due to how the expression is parsed. The following

```
if (1 == $x = 1 && $x) {
    echo "Hello world!";
}
```

results in an "Undefined variable: x" and does *not* echo, but

```
if (1 == ($x = 1) && $x) {
    echo "Hello world!";
}
```

"works" and emits *Hello world!* as expected.

This is because the former is equivalent to

```
if (1 == ($x = (1 && $x))) {
    echo "Hello world!";
}
```

and the use of $x is *inside* the expression that will be used for the assignment. Since this is evaluated before the assignment takes effect, $x is still an "undefined variable" according to PHP.

Solutions:

- Use parenthesis as shown; or,
- Avoid variable assignments in conditional expressions, which I recommend.

---

Although [operator precedence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php) is the primary scapegoat, the first form is *not* equivalent to `(1 == $x) = (1 && $x)` which is the derivation when directly following the precedence table. If it were parsed in such a manner it would result in a "syntax error, = unexpected".

This parsing is a quirk of PHP and differs from C grammar rules. (The YACC rules for PHP can be found in [zend_language_parser.y](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_TRUNK/Zend/zend_language_parser.y).)

- PHP: `1 && $x = 2` -> `1 && ($x = 2)`, as per the above stated equivalency. This happens even though `&&` is stated to have a higher precedence.
- C: `1 && x = 2` -> `(1 && x) = 2`, invalid syntax: "lvalue required as left operand of assignment". In C, the `&&` operator really does have higher precedence in an expression.

This same behavior is evident when replacing `&&` with `==`: despite an assignment having a lower  documented priority, the simple precedence table is misleading and inaccurate when assignments are part of expressions.

In conclusion, ***`$x = expr` as part of an expression is parsed equivalently to `($x = (expr))`*** where `expr` can itself be a complex expression containing operators and other expressions.

Comment: Damn, i thought it would parse from left to right, like it solves the if-clause from left to right, too. Thank you :)

Comment: it's not parsing, it's [operator precedence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php)

Comment: @user2864740, Operator precedence did exist prior to computer language parsing.

Comment: @Sorin [Parser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing#Parser): "A parser is a software component that takes input data (frequently text) and builds a data structure – often some kind of parse tree, abstract syntax tree or other hierarchical structure – giving a structural representation of the input, checking for correct syntax in the process."

Comment: @Sorin I do not believe that operator precedence, as given in that table, explains the issue accurately. I've added an argument against such.